# Package CBLAS not found

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, compiling

I'm running ubuntu in order to compile a software, and it cannot seem to find cblas. I have libatlas, liblapack, libopenblas, and libgsl installed and updated to the latest version. I am not sure what the reason could be for this.

[ubuntu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGIie.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? What are you compiling? What is the exact commands you are using? Your question needs more detail.

Comment: I am installing a software that is an extension of PETSc and SLEPc. It unfortunately has very little documentation. I am using the command cmake .

Comment: Would it be useful to upload the tar file?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Try `sudo apt install libblas-dev`. Also try contacting the software developer, because openblas should be enough. What software are you trying to compile?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.